# Passing and using function as constructor argument in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How to create a class that takes function as a constructor argument. Then, use this function at some later point in the class.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can have a property with a function type just like you would with any other type:

```
class A(val f: () -> Unit) {

    fun foo() {
        f()
    }

}
```

From here, you can pass that function to the constructor as a method reference:

```
fun bar() {
    println("this is bar")
}

val a = A(::bar)
a.foo()             // this is bar
```

Or as a lambda:

```
val a = A({ println("this is the lambda") })
```

And you can even do the usual syntactic sugar for lambdas that are the last parameter of a function (although this is getting a little wild):

```
val a = A { println("this is the lambda") }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one constructor declarations you can use this

```
...

private var listener : (() -> Unit)? = null

constructor(context: Context, listener: (() -> Unit)?) : this(context){
        this.listener = listener
}

constructor(context: Context) : super(context, attrs = null)

...
```

Answer (score 1):

A real world example can be observed in `SynchronizedLazyImpl`, the class backing `lazy` delegates.

```
public fun <T> lazy(lock: Any?, initializer: () -> T): Lazy<T> = 
    SynchronizedLazyImpl(initializer, lock)
```

When we use `val x by lazy {...}`, the `initializer`, passed as a lambda, is actually stored as a property in an instance of `SynchronizedLazyImpl` and called later when the corresponding `val x` is being accessed for the first time.